# Django output Fixtures from UserTeams

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to print a list of fixtures for the logged in player, where the fixtures they can view are only those for the teams they are a member of. Basically I want to output the fixtures where the hometeamID/awayteamID = each teamID in UserTeams where the userID = request.user.

Fixtures model:

```
class Fixtures(models.Model):
    fixture = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    hometeamID = 
  models.ForeignKey(Team,related_name='team1',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   awayteamID = 
  models.ForeignKey(Team,related_name='team2',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    homegoals = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    awaygoals = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    played = models.NullBooleanField()
```

UserTeams model:

```
class UserTeams(models.Model):
    userID = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teamID = models.ForeignKey(Team,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Fixtures View:

```
def fixturesview(request):

    query = Fixtures.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'teammanager/fixtures.html', {
    "fixtures": query
})
```

HTML:

```
<p>Fixtures</p>

{%for team in teams%}

    <h3>{{fixtures.fixture}}</h3>

{%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about - finding the teams for the user by

```
teams = UserTeams.objects.values_list('teamID', flat=True).filter(userId=user)
```

and then use this in

```
fixtures = Fixtures.objects.filter(Q(hometeamID__in=teams) | Q(awayteamID__in=teams))
```

However, IMHO, the names of these foreign fields should not end in ID.